# How do I send an ARRAY to a CLIENT in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, sockets, networking, client

So I know I can `Socket.puts` text to my clients, but how would I send something like an array?  I want to send a whole array to a client, but I'm not sure how I'd go about that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize the object in one or another way. One of the most popular ways as of now is JSON. You can turn an object into a string:

```
require "json"
[:foo, "bar"].to_json
# => "[\"foo\",\"bar\"]"
```

send that string, and then decode it on the machine at the other end:

```
require "json"
JSON.parse("[\"foo\",\"bar\"]")
# => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Notice that the standard "json" library looses the distinction between a string and a symbol. If that matters, then look for a similar library or a serialization method.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not really familiar with json--do you know of any good tutorials?

Comment: JSON is a common format, not just for Ruby, so you will find a lot of materials on the internet. Particularly for Ruby, look at the documentation for the json library.